# How to store custom properties that use int and float vector property to json?

Tags: python, custom-properties

I wrote a simple code that gets the custom properties I've added to materials and stores them in a dictionary, then this dictionary I write to json file. And it worked until I added **IntVectorProperty** and **FloatVectorProperty** params and got`TypeError: Object of type bpy_prop_array is not JSON serializable`

```
params = {}
custom_props = active_mat.my_custom_properties
for attr_name in custom_props.__annotations__:
    params[attr_name] = getattr(active_mat.my_custom_properties, attr_name)

with open(self.filepath, "w") as file:
   file.write(json.dumps(params, indent=4))
```

It didn't look like something hard to fix but I've failed, I've found some old implementations on the internet but they didn't work because **bpy_prop_array** object does not support indexing anymore or so

Comment: You can turn them into normal lists with `list(prop)`.

Comment: Well, it's a possible solution, but it leads to another problem - filtering custom attributes by type because there are string enums for example. I didn't come up with an idea of how to implement it correctly.